# does tramp actually copy file from remote to local?

Tags: tramp

when working in terminal with `ssh` I think what gets transferred is just the characters of the screen in view.

while in emacs tramp mode working with remote files, I'm not sure, does it copy files to cache in local ?

what are the background mechanisms ?

did the `scp` / `ssh` during open specify how it works ? or how do they different with each other ?

Comment: You can have a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Connection-types . The tl;dr seems to be that the file is always copied locally, but the transfer method changes. Note that the behavior is not the same as editing with ssh: with ssh you can have latency at all times, with tramp you only have latency when opening, saving or otherwise accessing the remote environment (e.g. for completion).